# Quaternion to Radians

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm writing a node to control my robot, but the odom orientation is in quaternions and the algorithm I have uses angles(radians). How do I convert this? There probably is some function that does this?

Anyone knows?

Thx so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205699/quaternion-to-radians/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2015-03-23**:
Have you tried Google? Something like "ros quaternion to euler"? We do expect a little effort of your own here ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11545/plotprint-rpy-from-quaternion/#17106). It has examples of nodes in roscpp and rospy that do the conversion. If you just want to run the conversion in your code you can strip out the relevant function calls.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1